# How can I create suitable methods for reading employee information in Python

Tags: python, class

Here I have created constructor and set values for employee. But I have to  Create suitable methods for reading employee information. Here I have input the employee information from outside the class. So, how can I create method to scan employee information

```
class Employee():

    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary, dep):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.dep = dep
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print ("Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary,  ", depatment: ", self.dep)


name={}
salary={}
dep={}
emp={}


for i in range (1,3):
    print("Enter Your Details for Employee %d" % (i))
    name[i]=input("Enter Your Name for employee:")
    salary[i]=float(input("Enter Your Salary for employee:"))
    dep[i]=input("Enter Your department for employee:")
    emp[i] = Employee(name[i], salary[i],dep[i])

print("____________________________________________________")

for i in range (1,3):
    emp[i].displayEmployee()

print ("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what this scan employee information method should do. You have the one already there.
You could try the following simplified code:

```
class Employee():

    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary, dep):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.dep = dep
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print ("Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary,  ", depatment: ", self.dep)

employees = []

for i in range (1,3):
    print("Enter Your Details for Employee %d" % (i))
    name = input("Enter Your Name for employee:")
    salary = float(input("Enter Your Salary for employee:"))
    dep = input("Enter Your department for employee:")
    employees.append(Employee(name, salary,dep))


for employee in employees:
    employee.displayEmployee()
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends largely on how your employee data is stored. If you are reading employee information from a csv file in the same directory, you could use os to get current directory location and pandas' `read_csv` to import the data from the file location as follows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

class Employee():

    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, emp_name, filename='all_employees_file.csv'): 
        self.file_loc = os.getcwd()+filename
        self.df = pd.read_csv(file_loc)
        self.name = emp_name
        self.salary = df['salary'][df['name']==self.name]
        self.dep = df['dep'][df['name']==self.name]
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print ("Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary,  ", depatment: ", self.dep)

billy = Employee('Billy McFarland')

billy.name #returns employee name
billy.salary #returns employee salary
billy.dep #returns employee department

billy.displayEmployee # To print as per sample in question
```

Also, based on code snippet in question, I assume that your intention is to use the class for creating a single object for a single employee. If so, `empCount` will not be of much use as each employee will be called on as a new instance of the `Employee()` class object. I would recommend either placing `empCount` outside of the class altogether and iterate through each employee, adding to `empCount` and creating an instance of `Employee()` for each if you intend to call the class for each individual. If planning on doing something for all employees, I would recommend building a single class object for the whole file for all employees. From this you could have `displayEmployee(self, name)` return details for any employee by feeding in their name.

Answer (score 0):

```
A slight change on your code only
# Generally you assign object by assigning it to class like object = class_name
# THen you invoke or call a method by object.function_inside_class ,,, 
#for you x.displayEmployee
class Employee():
    empCount = 0
    def __init__(self, name, salary, dep):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.dep = dep
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print ("Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary,  ", 
                       depatment: ", self.dep)

 name={}
 salary={}
 dep={}
 emp={}

 p=Employee                      #creating object or instances
for i in range (1,3):
    print("Enter Your Details for Employee %d" % (i))
    name[i]=input("Enter Your Name for employee:")
    salary[i]=float(input("Enter Your Salary for employee:"))
    dep[i]=input("Enter Your department for employee:")
    emp[i] = Employee(name[i], salary[i],dep[i])

print("____________________________________________________")

for i in range (1,3):
    p.displayEmployee(emp[i])                # invoking method call by
                                         # p.class = method , where p is object
print ("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)
```

Comment: This gives **Error**, as `displayEmployee()` takes **no** parameter.

Comment: it is perfectly working just pass p.displayEmployee(emp[i]), i already checked in my pc so, just do the print section of print employee as if of your code other is ok